# PCRE php regex to match groups correctly

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following sample text :

```
tabela de Preço 18654 TONER XEROX 106R01632 MA(6000/6010 117.90 129.90 18656 TONER XEROX 106R01634 PR 6000/6010 179.00 199.00 UDP COMPUT ADORES IBYTE 32607 UDP A - GCL(CDCP 2.41,2,500) 747.00 829.90 32148 UDP A - GCL(CDCP 2.41,2,500) 747.00 829.90 32149 UDP A - GCL(CDCP 2.41,4,500,DVD) 769.90 879.00 32555 UDP A - GCL(CDCP 2.41,4,500,DVD) 769.90 879.00 32490 UDP A - ICL(CDCP 2.41,2,500) 747.00 829.90 32150 UDP A - ICL(CDCP 2.41,2,500) 747.00 829.90 32024 UDP A - ICW10(CDC 2.8,4,500,DVD) 1 260.001 399.90 32445 UDP A - ICW10(CDC 2.8,4,500,DVD) 1 260.001 399.90 31060 UDP A - ISW10PRO(CDCP 2.41,4,500)SLI1 349.901 549.90 32356 UDP F - GCL(I3 6G 3.7,4,500,DVD,LT) 1 699.001 929.90
```

and I have to match it in groups like:

```
code, description,value1,value2
```

using that excerpt as a source:

```
"18654 TONER XEROX 106R01632 MA(6000/6010 117.90 129.90"
```

its a product and i need to parse it as follows:

```
"18654" is the code
"TONER XEROX 106R01632 MA(6000/6010" is the description
"117.90" is the value1
"129.90" is the value2
```

but the description,value1 and value2 lengths varies and while I have products that have value1 like "117.90" I also have "1 699.00" and "90.00".

Im trying the following regex to capture the groups,but it matches correctly some not the whole source string:

```
(?<code>\d{5})\s{1}(?<description>.{20,35})\s{1}(?<value1>\d{2,3}\.\d{2})\s{1}(?<value2>\d{2,3}\.\d{2})
```

How do I capture the groups correctly for each product in this sample source string using pcre (php) ?

I have the following regex101.com url to show what I have tryied
https://regex101.com/r/Smh2KA/3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to explain how the different parts of the match are supposed to be recognized.

Comment: It's never necessary to write `{1}` in a regexp. That's the default, and adding it just make the RE look more complex.

Comment: Why are all the data on a single line?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have no control over the data source. This string is from a pdf parsed/converted to plain text, so the one line big string

Comment: @Barmar The regex that I need is supposed to parse the whole input string and capture the groups as follows:
code is 5 number fixed group that starts the product. 
description is the following group prepended of 1 space character.
value1 is the next one, can be "117.90", "1 699.00" or "90.00" and so is value2 the last one. Then, the sequence repeats until the end of the input string

Comment: Try [`(\d{5})\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/xA5iTK/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your answer was the most accurate so far ! 34 matches, but it still have some minor issues like that product : 
 "32025 UDP N - IWW10(PDC 3.3,4,500,DVD) 1 469.001 629.90"
the value1 is matched as "469.001" where it should be "1 469.00"
and the value2  is matched as  "629.90"  where it should be "1 629.90"
Because of the source pdf is converted to plain text, the value1 ad value2 in that case are so next that in that situation they end up matched incorrect. Could you help again to address this issue?

the url with updated regex: https://regex101.com/r/Smh2KA/5

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: If `value1` can be `629.90` or `1 629.90`, how is it supposed to know whether the `1` is part of the description or value1?

Comment: @Barmar Good question! Both values has to be 2 decimal precison and the description is suposed to be 35 characters length, maybe a issue in the converting of the source pdf, but we can see that when the value1 is greater then 1000, the first number will be closest to the descripiont and the both vaues need to be 2 decimals, so 3 decimal is wrong

Comment: @CaioMaia: It isn't a problem since the two values are linked: val2/val1 ~ 1.1, conclusion val2 has max 1 digit more than val1. My answer uses that to separate the description part and the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~\b (?<id>\d{5}) \s
           (?<desc>.*?) \s*+
           (?<val1>
               (?: \d \s*(?=[\d\s]*\.\d\s?\d\s*(?<c>(?(c)\g{c})\s*\d)) )+
               \.\d\s?\d
           ) \s*
           (?<val2>\g{c}\d?\.\d{2})~x';
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/xCxwQh/1)

The subpattern in val1 checks if for each digit in the integer part of val1 there's a digit for the integer part in val2. That's why this part is a bit complicated. But the advantage is that confusion is no more possible between the description part and the first value.

val1 subpattern details:

```
(?:
    \d \s* # 1 digit in val1 (and an eventual space)
    (?= # lookahead that checks if for this digit there's also
        # a digit in val2
        [\d\s]*\.\d\s?\d\s* # reach val2
        (?<c> # open a capture group c
             (?(c)\g{c}) # conditional: if the capture group c has already captured
                         # something then start the group with the backreference \g{c}
                         # (this means that the non-captured group has been repeated
                         # at least once)
             \s*\d       # add the next digit to c
        )
    )
)+ # repeat the non-capturing group
\.\d\s?\d
```

Note that this pattern needs a lot of steps to succeed. If you need to use it on a big input, I suggest to split the string before each code and then to search each part with preg_match and the previous pattern (you can start it with the `^` anchor instead of `\b`):

```
$parts = preg_split('~\b(?=\d{5}\b)~', $str);
$result = [];
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    preg_match($pattern, $part, $m);
    $result[] = [$m['id'], $m['desc'], $m['val1'], $m['val2']];
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me, your regex seems to be the most accurate so far, I am checking it against a bigger input string right now.

Comment: @CaioMaia: I will add a note about big inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a regex like

```
\b(?<code>\d{5})\s+(?<description>.*?)\s+(?<value1>\d[,\d\s]*\.\d{2})\s*(?<value2>\d[,\d\s]*\.\d{2})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RMBvXv/6)

A version with comments:

```
\b                           # leading word boundary
(?<code>\d{5})               # 5 digits
\s+                          # 1+ whitespaces
(?<description>.*?)          # any 0+ non-line break chars
\s+                          # 1+ whitespaces
(?<value1>\d[,\d\s]*\.\d{2}) # a float number with 2-digit fractional part
\s*                          # 0+ whitespaces
(?<value2>\d[,\d\s]*\.\d{2}) # a float number
```

**NOTE**: If your float values (value1 and value2) contain `,` as thousand separators and `.` as a decimal separator, adust their patterns as `\d[,\d]*\.\d+`. If the thousand separator is a space, use `\d[\d\s]*\.\d+`. If the thousand separator is a space and a decimal separator is a comma, use `\d[\d\s]*,\d+`. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Why do you have `,` in `[,\d\s]`*? The question doesn't say that `value1` can contain comma.

Comment: @Barmar: Just in case there is. It can be removed if there can't be any.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you again for helping me, but as you can see it is quite challenging !  Well, the issue is still there,  because in that case: "32365 UDP N - IWL(PQCP 2.67,4,500) 989.901 099.90 " value1 is parsed as 989.901 which is an invalid number ( should be 989.90 - two decimals  ) and so value2 is not correctly parsed too ( 099.90 ), as a consequence. Any other idea to deal with that issue?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The thousand separator is actually a space, no comma there for the values. The problem is that when value2 is grater then 1000, the space is added as a thousand separator so the first number of value2 becomes the following of the last number of value1, so no space between them in that case, but for value1 and value2 less then 1000

Comment: What doesn't it match now?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tryied \b(?<code>\d{5})\s+(?<description>.*?)\s+(?<value1>\d[\d\s]*\.\d+)\s*(?<value2>\d[\d\s]*\.\d+) , as you suggested ( space as thousand separator ) and the issue with value1 and value2 grater then 1000 is still present, as ou can see here : https://regex101.com/r/RMBvXv/7

note that products: 
32023 UDP GAMER - IGW10(I3 6G 3.7,4,SSD2402 159.002 399.00
31178 UDP GAMER - IGW10(I7 3.4,8,1,DVD,PV)4 819.905 499.90
these are not being parsed correct, so the matches are not too

Comment: You should not test *that* regex. See [this one](https://regex101.com/r/RMBvXv/8).

Answer (score 0):

This one should work :

`(?<code>\d{5})\s+(?<description>((?!\d{2,}\.\d{1,}).)*)\s+(?<value1>\d{2,3}\.\d{1,})((?!\d{2,}\.\d{1,}).)*(?<value2>\d{2,}\.\d{1,})`

Here is a [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t3MGX6/1) based on your initial text and [here](https://regex101.com/r/MaV8w2/2) a simplier one

It returns 35 matches as expected, including this one which was a little tricky because value1 and value2 where not separated by a simple space :

```
31069 UDP GAMER - IGW10(I7 3.4,8,1,DVD,PV)4 499.0 04 999.90
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but it is not what I wanted cause the whole input string needs to be parsed and it is almost entire produts with some dummy string mixed. Your regex is not matching most of the source as is expected 35 matches not 17.

Comment: @CaioMaia I've updated my answer, this one should match your needs. ;)